# Cleartool - Merging from local folder

Tags: version, clearcase

I've a tool to generate some configuration files, where these configuration files are kept in clearcase to run some setup scripts. The version and merge details for these files are not so important, hence some of the developers directly checkout from the main branch and update it rather than creating new version.
But that has some issues as they sometime makes unnecessary versions though the files are identical. There are approx 2000 config files and checking out and checking in will take long time. Is there any way to merge to a branch from local folder? If Yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those developers are using snapshot view, they can simply modify the file without checkout ("hijacked file").
If they are using dynamic view, they can make a private copy which will eclipse the one selected by the view ("eclipsed file").

In both cases, the idea is for them to never have to make a checkin (and avoid any unnecessary version).

Comment: Are you saying that overwriting a file in the dynamic view will hide the original files and this file can be used for merge? The files will be generated only to local drive.

Comment: @sarat: if we are talking "dynamic views", an "eclipsed file" will be a private one and can be modified at will, included with a local merge (not a clearcase merge though)